# General solution to $f'(x)-(\alpha/x) f(x) = c$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the general solution to the FODE $f'(x)-(\alpha/x) f(x) = c$. In the case of $c=0$, I have been able to show that the general solution is $f(x)=c \exp(\int (\alpha/x)dx)$. I am stuck as to whether this is possible more generally when $c \neq 0$.

Comment: It's a [First Order Linear EDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Linear_to_the_nth_order_equations)

Comment: $x^{-α}$ is an integrating factor, $(x^{-α}f(x))'=cx^{-α}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us think about $x\lt0$ and $x\gt0$ separately. Now, the equation is of the form $y'(x)+p(x)y(x)=q(x)$, where $p(x)=\frac{\alpha}{x}$. So the integrating factor is $\exp(\int{p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x})$. For $x\lt0$, $\int{p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}=\alpha{\ln(-x)}+C_-$, hence $\exp(\int{p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x})=\exp(\alpha{\ln(-x)}+C_-)=\exp(C_-)(-x)^{\alpha}=A_-(-x)^{\alpha}$. For $x\gt0$, $\int{p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}=\alpha{\ln(x)}+C_+$, hence $\exp(\int{p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x})=\exp(\alpha{\ln(x)}+C_+)=\exp(C_+)x^{\alpha}=A_+x^{\alpha}$. As such, we have $[A_-(-x)^{\alpha}f(x)]'=cA_-(-x)^{\alpha}$ for $x\lt0$ and $[A_+x^{\alpha}f(x)]'=cA_+x^{\alpha}$ for $x\gt0$, or simply $[(-x)^{\alpha}f(x)]'=c(-x)^{\alpha}$ and $[x^{\alpha}f(x)]'=cx^{\alpha}$ respectively. This means that $(-x)^{\alpha}f(x)=-\frac{c(-x)^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}+b_-$ and $x^{\alpha}f(x)=\frac{cx^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}+b_+$. This simplifies to $f(x)=\frac{c}{\alpha+1}+\frac{b_-}{(-x)^{\alpha}}$ for $x\lt0$ and $f(x)=\frac{c}{\alpha+1}+\frac{b_+}{x^{\alpha}}$ for $x\gt0$.

Answer (score 1):

Case 01: if $\alpha =0$
it's clear that the solution will be under the form $f(x)=cx+c_1$. 
Case 02: if $\alpha=1$
by multiplying the equation by $\dfrac{1}{x} $ we find
$$ \dfrac{1}{x}f'(x)-\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}f(x)=\dfrac{c}{x}  $$
Which is equivalent to
$$ \big( \dfrac{1}{x}f(x)\big)^{'} =\dfrac{c}{x}  $$
Thus, by integrating both sides we get
$$ \dfrac{1}{x}f(x)= \begin{cases} 
c \ln( x )+c_1, \text{if} \hspace{0.5cm} x>0\\   
c \ln(-x )+c_2, \text{if}   \hspace{0.5cm}  x<0
 \end{cases}$$
Hence,
$$ f(x)= \begin{cases} 
cx \ln( x )+c_1 x, \text{if} \hspace{0.5cm} x>0\\   
c x \ln(-x )+c_2 x, \text{if}   \hspace{0.5cm}  x<0
 \end{cases}$$
Case 03: if $ x \notin \{0,1 \} $
By multiplying the equation by $\dfrac{1}{x^{ \alpha}}$ we find
$$ \dfrac{1}{x^{\alpha}}f'(x)-\dfrac{\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}f(x)=\dfrac{c}{x^{\alpha}}  $$
Which is equivalent to
$$ \big( \dfrac{1}{x^{\alpha}}f(x)\big)^{'} =\dfrac{c}{x^{\alpha}}  $$
Thus, by integrating both sides we get
$$ \dfrac{1}{x^{\alpha}}f(x)=-\dfrac{c}{(\alpha-1)x^{\alpha-1}}+c_1$$
Hence, 
$$ f(x)=-\dfrac{c}{(\alpha-1)}x+c_1 x^{\alpha}$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this is a Cauchy-Euler equation if you multiply through by $x:$
$$x\,f'(x)-\alpha\,f(x)=cx.$$
We assume a solution of the form $f(x)=a\,x^b$ and substitute in the ODE to get the particular solution:
\begin{align*}
ab\,x^b-\alpha a\,x^b&=cx\\
a(b-\alpha)x^b&=cx\\
b&=1\\
a(1-\alpha)&=c\\
a&=\frac{c}{1-\alpha},\quad \alpha\not=1\\
f(x)&=\frac{cx}{1-\alpha}.
\end{align*}
The homogeneous solution is just $C\,x^\alpha,$ which you can see by inspection. Hence the general solution is
$$f(x)=\frac{cx}{1-\alpha}+C\,x^\alpha.$$
That works for $\alpha\not=1.$ If $\alpha=1,$ the original DE is
$$x\,f'(x)-f(x)=cx,$$
with corresponding solution
$$f(x)=Cx+cx\ln(x).$$
The last term is the standard variation of parameters procedure applied to Cauchy-Euler equations. So we can write the general solution as
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
Cx+cx\ln(x),&\alpha=1,\; x>0\\
\dfrac{cx}{1-\alpha}+C\,x^\alpha,&\alpha\not=1.
\end{cases}
$$